# How can I combine consecutive keys of an array depending on their values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array similar to this:

```
$stuff = array("a"=>"115","b"=>"0","c"=>"1","d"=>"0","e"=>"11","f"=>"326","g"=>"9","h"=>"1","i"=>"12","j"=>"0","k"=>"56");
```

What I want to do is concatenate the strings of the keys only where they are consecutive and their values are under 10 - note this includes keeping solitary keys with values under 10 too. I don't need to keep the actual values. In other words, the desired result in this case would be:

```
Array ( [0] => bcd [1] => gh [2] => j)
```

So there might be just two consecutive keys that need to be joined, or there might be more (eg as many as 5). I'm not sure how to 'look ahead' through the array to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to look ahead but keep the past in mind.

```
$consecutive = '';
foreach($stuff as $k => $v) {
    if ($v < 10) // or what ever condition you need
        $consecutive .= $k;
    else {
        if ($consecutive) $res[] = $consecutive; // if exist add it 
        $consecutive= ''; // and reset 
    }
}
if ($con) $res[] = $con; //adding last element if exist as @Joffrey  comment
```

Now `$res` will be your desire output

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/E9D1F)

Comment: You need an extra test outside the loop to add a possible non-empty `consecutive` at the end of the data

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz absolutely right  - edited - thanks!